# jquery on method not working with second parameter

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use the jquery on method but I am getting error when I add the dynamic selector parameter:

Error:

```js
$('body').on('click', '.main-menu', function() {
  console.log(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-menu">Menu</div>
```

No error:

```js
$('body').on('click', function() {
  console.log(1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main-menu">Menu</div>
```

What could be the cause of this?

Comment: What error are you getting? That would definitely help to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I don't see any errors.

Comment: No errors are coming up for either of the snippets - they both work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try the `.click` method

```
$('.main-menu').click(function() {
  console.log(1);
});
```

Comment: I tried everything but this, such as setTimer and MutationObserver to try and add an event listener to a pop-up, but the issue was a new feature (.on) imposed on an older version of jQuery. Thanks! This worked for me.